# A digital copy of oil painting

Tags: single-word-requests

When we search for digital copies of oil artworks, it is often exist many different variants varying in color and size. For example, below are two variants of *The Boyhood of Raleigh* by John Everett Millais. (Source: [WikiArt](https://www.wikiart.org/en/john-everett-millais/the-boyhood-of-raleigh).)

The first copy, 25% of its size on WikiArt:

[image]

The second copy, the original size of the file:

[image]

Is there a word to describe such copies? I mean, the word should stress the fact that it is the same painting but different attempts to convert it to digital form.

The words "copy", "variant", or "digital image" are too broad, to my opinion. The word "digitization" seems to be describing the process rather than its result.

Comment: Isn't the usual word [**reproduction**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/reproduction)? In the pre-digital world there might be numerous prints of an artwork varying by size and tone.

Comment: Why is "digital image" too broad?